# Overriding public functions in jigoshop

Tags: php, wordpress, jigoshop

I need to override the public function that returns the discount percentage in jigoshop

```
/**
 * Returns the products sale value, either with or without a percentage
 *
 * @return string HTML price of product (with sales)
 */
public function get_calculated_sale_price_html()
{
    if ($this->is_on_sale()) {
        if (strstr($this->sale_price, '%')) {
            return '<del>'.jigoshop_price($this->regular_price).'</del>
                <ins>'.jigoshop_price($this->get_price()).'</ins><br/>
                <span class="discount">'.sprintf(__('%s off!', 'jigoshop'), $this->sale_price).'</span>';
        } else {
            return '<del>'.jigoshop_price($this->regular_price).'</del>
                <ins>'.jigoshop_price($this->sale_price).'</ins>';
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

I tried with

```
if (!function_exists('calculated_price')) {
    function calculated_price(){
        if ($this->is_on_sale()) {
            if (strstr($this->sale_price, '%')) {
                return '<del>'.jigoshop_price($this->regular_price).'</del>
                    <ins>'.jigoshop_price($this->get_price()).'</ins><br/>
                    <span class="discount">'.$this->sale_price.'</span>';
            } else {
                return '<del>'.jigoshop_price($this->regular_price).'</del>
                    <ins>'.jigoshop_price($this->sale_price).'</ins>';
            }
        }

        return '';
        }
}

add_action('get_calculated_sale_price_html', 'calculated_price');
```

And I tried with `add_filter()` but no luck.

Is it possible to modify the existing public function?

Comment: do you want to add or override a public function ?

Comment: OOP is a great thing, especially if your class [`extends`](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) an existing one...

Comment: I need to override existing function `get_calculated_sale_price_html()` that is inside `jigoshop_product` class that extends `Jigoshop_Base` class.

Answer (score 1):

For adding your new function, I assume you have a main class that contains your function, so, add a new class that extends that,

```
class myclass extends already_externs_class {
        function calculated_price(){
        }
}
```

In this case, you have to instantiate from new class that you've written.

Comment: Yes, you have simply to extends your class if you want to do a specific action. Avoid to change your functions with these kind of mechanism like `add_action` ... it is an anti-pattern

Comment: With this I can add my own function, which is great, but what about the old one? That one will still be there. I only need to modify one thing in the existing function.